# How do I test modal dialogs with Selenium?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm getting started with [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/) and trying to test a webapp that's full of modal dialogs (`window.showModalDialog`).

Recording the test seems to work (except there's nothing in the log when the dialog pops up) but they don't play back properly. The script actually opens the window (triggered by a button click), but then just waits indefinitely.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Selenium FAQ](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+Core+FAQ#SeleniumCoreFAQ-Ican%27tinteractwithapopupdialog.Myteststopsinitstracks!), Selenium apparently works with some types of dialogs but not others:

> I can't interact with a popup dialog.
>   My test stops in its tracks!
>
> You can, but only if the dialog is an
>   alert or confirmation dialog. Other
>   special dialogs can't be dismissed by
>   javascript, and thus currently cannot
>   be interacted with. These include the
>   "Save File", "Remember this Password"
>   (Firefox), and modal (IE) dialogs.
>   When they appear, Selenium can only
>   wring its hands in despair.
>
> To solve this issue, you may use a
>   workaround (if one exists); otherwise
>   you may have to exclude the test from
>   your automated corpus. For the "Save
>   File" dialog in Firefox, a custom
>   template may be specified when running
>   via the RC that will always cause the
>   file to be downloaded to a specified
>   location, without querying the user
>   (see
>   http://forums.openqa.org/thread.jspa?messageID=31350).
>   The "Remember this Password" dialog
>   should not appear again after you've
>   chosen to remember it. Currently there
>   is not much that can be done about IE
>   modal dialogs.

I seem to remember someone working around this with an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that dismissed the dialog.

Comment: The problem is that these aren't small dialogs--they are rich interfaces that need tested. I'll try something else, I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have been using Selenium IDE to test jQuery modals for quite sometime now, I never faced any problem. Here are the things I do to ensure that the test executes properly on playback:

- execute the script at the slowest possible speed
- when the modal opens, I use the waitForElementPresent command to verify the presence of at least one of the constituent elements on the page; argument being, if one element loads properly, it is safe to assume that all the elements and hence the modal window loaded up properly.

Hope this helps. If you want further help, you can share the code with me alongwith the error in execution that IDE throws out to you.

Answer (score 2):

Modal window hacked:)
http://seleniumdeal.blogspot.com/2009/01/handling-modal-window-with-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle pop up alert in Selenium IDE

right click on the element (in this case your pop up window) there are some command you can choose. There's also a show all available commands whiche might be a help.
You should use AssertElementPreset and I guess the best locator in this case is CSS. So you can choose AssertElementPresent.

Or

you can use two command on Selenium IDE

```
selectWindow | null
verifyElementPresent | css=div.content
```

Hope this helps!