# Selenium RC - selenium-browserbot.js error

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm writing some automated tests in C# and a JavaScript error is thrown when I try to click on a button that will submit changes made to a web form.  The error I am recieving is:

```
An error has occured in the script on this page 
Line:  2004 
Char:  9 
Error:  Permission denied 
Code:  0 
URL:  file:///C:/DOCUME~1/nkinney/LOCALS~1/Temp/customProfileDir6c0c7d7226cc463fb­b1a7f6253c4df62/core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js
```

Once the test is finished, the error will still be displayed if I manually click on the button while selenium is running.

The line in selenium to select this button is:

```
selenium.Click("//input[contains(@id, 'SubmitBtn')]");
```

I've also tried submit.

A pop-up should be displayed asking the user to confirm they want to make the changes.  This error is thrown before the pop-up is displayed and after Selenium 'clicks' on the button.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should also point out the browser opens a moto window.  I think this may be the issue, but I'm unsure of what I need to do in order to work around it.

Comment: When you click submit is the test moving to another domain?

Comment: No, it is not.  I need to make changes fo some fields on the page, then I get a modal window me to confirm I want to make the changes after i click on a sudmit button.  The problem is I get this java script error after selemiun clicks on the button.  I know it is clicking on the button as the entire id is displayed in the selenium server window.

Comment: Is there any update regarding this issue ?  I am still facing the same  problem

Comment: Have you tried to loosen the internet security settings on the test-machine? It may help.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I found that Selenium is unable to work with custom modal dialog boxes.  That said, I don't think I will be able to use Selenium to automate UI testing in our current release.  Thanks to anyone who looked at this post.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Selenium FAQ](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+Core+FAQ#SeleniumCoreFAQ-Ican%27tinteractwithapopupdialog.Myteststopsinitstracks!)

> I can't interact with a popup dialog. My test stops in its tracks!
>
> You can, but only if the dialog is an alert or confirmation dialog.
>   Other special dialogs can't be dismissed by javascript, and thus
>   currently cannot be interacted with. These include the "Save File",
>   "Remember this Password" (Firefox), and modal (IE) dialogs. When they
>   appear, Selenium can only wring its hands in despair.
>
> To solve this issue, you may use a workaround (if one exists);
>   otherwise you may have to exclude the test from your automated corpus.
>   For the "Save File" dialog in Firefox, a custom template may be
>   specified when running via the RC that will always cause the file to
>   be downloaded to a specified location, without querying the user (see
>   http://forums.openqa.org/thread.jspa?messageID=31350). The "Remember
>   this Password" dialog should not appear again after you've chosen to
>   remember it. Currently there is not much that can be done about IE
>   modal dialogs.

Do you have the option of seeing if the test runs in another browser (Firefox, Chrome)?

A very similar answer is also here: [How do I test modal dialogs with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866856/how-do-i-test-modal-dialogs-with-selenium)