# SeleniumRC Script error - selenium-browserbot.js

Tags: selenium-rc

**Problem:**
 In our application, we have same locators(id) for submit images (link + form submit) in Popup and main window. Main window submit image executes two javascript functions for click event. While trying through selenium, I'm getting following selenium error and submit action not happened. Unable to process, even if I clicked manually on the browser, which was opened by Selenium. But this scenario is working fine if I do manually end to end.

I tried with FormSubmit and ClickAt..No luck... **Any trick/solution?**

I found similar thread without any solution --> Selenium RC - selenium-browserbot.js error (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380543/selenium-rc-selenium-browserbot-js-error)

**Environment:**
Browser: IE8
Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 16.0-b13
OS: Windows XP 5.1 x86
Selenium RC- selenium-server-1.0.3

**Selenium Error Message**

```
An error has occured in the script on this page 
Line:  2120 
Char:  9 
Error:  Permission denied 
Code:  0 
URL:  file:///C:/DOCUME~1/script1/LOCALS~1/Temp/customProfileDira540839f44a5460e8f29cdcb8f3632a7/core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js
Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?
```

**HTML Source**

```
<A onmouseover="imgOn('cmdSubmitbutton', 'submit');" onmouseout="imgOff('cmdSubmitbutton', 'submit');" onclick="return verifyAttachmentJS();submitOrder();" href="javascript:void(0);"><IMG title="Submit this form." border=0 name=cmdSubmitbutton src="/webtop/images/buttons/submit_off.gif"> </A>
```

**selenium RC command history**

```
type(desc1, asdasdas)
click(cmdAttachbutton)
click(cmdSubmitbutton)
click(cmdFinishbutton)
selectWindow(null)
type(ORD_TrackingNbr, 6666)
isElementPresent(cmdSubmitbutton)
clickAt(cmdSubmitbutton, 20,8)
```

**Selenium Log Console**

```
info(1331131785603): Executing: |type | findCnum | ABCDP60 |
info(1331131789088): Executing: |click | gobutton |  |
error(1331131792666): Caught an exception attempting to log location; this should get noticed soon!
error(1331131792666): Unexpected Exception: Permission denied
error(1331131792666): Exception details: name -> Error, number -> -2146828218, description -> Permission denied, message -> Permission denied
info(1331131795494): Executing: |selectFrame | relative=up |  |
info(1331131796275): Executing: |selectFrame | relative=up |  |
info(1331131797056): Executing: |getLocation |  |  |
info(1331131797494): Executing: |click | xpath=//a[@id="ABCDP60" or @name="ABCDP60" or @href="ABCDP60" or normalize-space(descendant-or-self::text())="ABCDP60" or @href="http://172.18.70.63/webtop/ABCDP60"] |  |
error(1331131806338): Caught an exception attempting to log location; this should get noticed soon!
error(1331131806338): Unexpected Exception: Permission denied
error(1331131806338): Exception details: name -> Error, number -> -2146828218, description -> Permission denied, message -> Permission denied
info(1331131808056): Executing: |click | //form[@id='form1']/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/a[4]/font/b |  |
info(1331131815478): Executing: |click | cmdZipbutton |  |
error(1331131815712): Caught an exception attempting to log location; this should get noticed soon!
error(1331131815712): Unexpected Exception: Permission denied
error(1331131815712): Exception details: name -> Error, number -> -2146828218, description -> Permission denied, message -> Permission denied
info(1331131835384): Executing: |selectWindow | name=attachdoc |  |
info(1331131865634): Executing: |type | desc1 | asdasdas |
info(1331131876431): Executing: |click | cmdAttachbutton |  |
info(1331131882290): Executing: |click | cmdSubmitbutton |  |
info(1331131888290): Executing: |click | cmdFinishbutton |  |
info(1331131894196): Executing: |selectWindow | null |  |
info(1331131894306): Executing: |type | ORD_TrackingNbr | 6666 |
info(1331131898399): Executing: |isElementPresent | cmdSubmitbutton |  |
info(1331131902290): Executing: |clickAt | cmdSubmitbutton | 20,8 |
info(1331132070023): Done appending missed logging messages
error(1331132070023): Caught an exception attempting to log location; this should get noticed soon!
error(1331132070023): Unexpected Exception: Permission denied
error(1331132070039): Exception details: name -> Error, number -> -2146828218, description -> Permission denied, message -> Permission denied
error(1331132115492): Caught an exception attempting to log location; this should get noticed soon!
error(1331132115492): Unexpected Exception: Permission denied
error(1331132115492): Exception details: name -> Error, number -> -2146828218, description -> Permission denied, message -> Permission denied
```