# Using Selenium How Can I test that a Save Dialog Box was displayed on the screen?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to programatically click the "save" button and test that the windows Save Dialog box appears: I have everything but the assert statement I believe. I don't know how to assert that my custom SaveDialogBox appears to the user.

```
[test]
public void Method_WhenThePersonIsNotfound_ClickingTheButtonSavesLetterToWordDocument
{
     //arrange
     CreateNewPage(); //creates IE window enters fields and clicks submit on first page.
     //act
     this.InternetExplorerDriver.FindElementById("SaveForm").Click(); //Clicks my button that should produce a save dialog box.

     //assert
     //Assert statement to verify that when button was clicked the save dialog box to save the letter in word appears.
```

Comment: So it's a web integration test then? What you're talking about has very little to do with NUnit and a lot to do with which framework you're using: Selenium, WatIN, etc.

Comment: Okay, I can rephrase the question, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can: [I can't interact with a popup dialog. My test stops in its tracks!](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+Core+FAQ). "Save File" is specifically mentioned as being unable to be interacted with by Selenium.

Comment: Same discussion over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866856/how-do-i-test-modal-dialogs-with-selenium, with a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Using exceptions for implementing logic is not a good practice, but maybe this fast solution could help:

```
try { 
      this.InternetExplorerDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();//Appears sometime
    } 
catch (NoAlertPresentException) 
    { 
      // this code will perform if no alert is shown
    }
```

### Also you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164894/selenium2-and-webdriver-alert) answer

Comment: I think this may work but in my unit test I need to assert something. should I                                    Assert.isFalse(this.InternetExplorerDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept());